# Creating a proper db context .NET Core 3

Tags: .net-core, dbcontext

I'm trying to explicitly create a db context in .NET Core 3 startup

I know I can do this in startup.cs ConfigureServices to inject a  dbcontext into the controller (which works fine):

```
String dbconn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:VerseDBConnectionStringMSSQL"];
services.AddDbContext<VerseDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbconn));
```

but I am trying to generalize the storage provider (and keep the controller code the same for all storage readers), so it takes an IVerseStorageReader interface, instead of a DB context (as I may want to read from memory, or xmlfile, etc) and use the same code in the controller, just switch it based on config in appsettings. One of the VerseStorageReaders takes a db context in constructor:

```
public class DBVerseReader : IVerseStorageReader
{
    private VerseDBContext _dbContext;
    public DBVerseReader(VerseDBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
...
}
```

My problem is: I can't quite figure out the syntax right for creating the db context explicitly. I'm very close (I think) but this doesn't work:

```
String dbconn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:VerseDBConnectionStringMySQL"];
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VerseDBContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(dbconn);
VerseDBContext x = optionsBuilder.UseMySql<VerseDBContext>(dbconn); <-- compile error
services.AddSingleton<IVerseStorageReader>(new DBVerseReader(x));
```

Can someone clue me on what I'm doing wrong? What I'm trying to inject is an instance of IVerseStorageReader, not a DBContext. There are overloads of VerseStorageReader that take a db context as input, and others which take other inputs (e.g. xmlfilename, etc)...so I want startup to add an instance of one of the IVerseStorageReaders and that gets injected (not a dbcontext injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the options from the builder after configuring it

```
String dbconn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:VerseDBConnectionStringMySQL"];
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VerseDBContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(dbconn);
DbContextOptions<VerseDBContext> options = optionsBuilder.Options;
VerseDBContext x = new VerseDBContext(options);
services.AddSingleton<IVerseStorageReader>(new DBVerseReader(x));
```

But since `DbContext` derived classes are usually registered as scoped, I would suggest you move the context into the factory delegate and register the service abstraction as scoped also.

```
String dbconn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:VerseDBConnectionStringMySQL"];
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VerseDBContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(dbconn);
DbContextOptions<VerseDBContext> options = optionsBuilder.Options;    
services.AddScoped<IVerseStorageReader>( sp => {
    VerseDBContext x = new VerseDBContext(options);
    return new DBVerseReader(x);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nkosi. Did you any idea how to apply for Oracle Data Provider?

Comment: @FairuzSulaiman have a look at the providers here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli there is one for oracle that should provide the details.